# Is it possible to refactor this statement to remove the subquery?

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2005

I'm trying to take data from one column, `MyTable.SSN`, and copy it to another in the same table, `MyTable.SSNWithDashes`, just formatted differently.  If `MyTable.SSN` doesn't have exactly 9 digits, I don't care to process it at all.

I've tried this:

```
IF( SELECT LEN( [SSN] ) FROM [MyTable] ) = 9
UPDATE [MyTable] SET [SSNWithDashes] = LEFT( [SSN], 3 ) + '-' + SUBSTRING( [SSN], 4, 2 ) + '-' + RIGHT( [SSN], 4 ) 
ELSE
UPDATE [MyTable] SET [SSNWithDashes] = NULL
```

While this works, it throws an error:

`Subquery returned more than 1 value. This is not permitted when the subquery follows =, !=, <, <= , >, >= or when the subquery is used as an expression.`

While I do understand what the warning is saying, I'm not really sure how to go about this differently.

How can I refactor this to remove that warning (and perhaps read a little cleaner)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
UPDATE dbo.[MyTable] 
  SET [SSNWithDashes] = CASE
  WHEN LEN(SSN) = 9 THEN 
    LEFT([SSN],3) + '-' + SUBSTRING([SSN],4,2) + '-' + RIGHT([SSN],4) 
  ELSE NULL
END;
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your `SSNWithDashes` is already `NULL` then

```
UPDATE dbo.[MyTable] 
  SET [SSNWithDashes]  = LEFT([SSN],3) + '-' + SUBSTRING([SSN],4,2) + '-' + RIGHT([SSN],4) 
WHERE LEN(SSN) = 9
```

Every other rows remain `NULL`

Comment: Your first line is a valuable disclaimer. Since if SSNWithDashes has any invalid data now for any row where LEN(SSN) is not 9, those rows will stay that way. Definitely a good approach if you know the nature of the data, but not the safest if you don't.

Comment: I agree with you, "safe" is the word. I answered based on _"If MyTable.SSN doesn't have exactly 9 digits, I don't care to process it at all."_ in the OP's question